# Attribute as name context broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm working with ContextBroker by inserting the data I retrieve from an API.

My problem is the following:

These attribute names are numeric and CB behaves strangely for example when I create this:

```
{
  "id": "pruebas999",
  "type": "typopruebas99",
  "2000": {
            "type": "float",
            "value": 2.4,
            "metadata": {
                "timestamp": {
                    "type": "Integer",
                    "value": 1550804920
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The information returns it in the following way, everything above the id and the type this is normal?

```
{
        "2000": {
            "type": "float",
            "value": 2.4,
            "metadata": {
                "timestamp": {
                    "type": "Integer",
                    "value": 1550804920
                }
            }
        },
        "id": "pruebas999",
        "type": "typopruebas99"
    }
```

On the other hand to be numerical values I do not know the name of those sensors I have thought to create another entity with the name of the sensors and make reference in it to each id then you can retrieve the information of that entity with the value of each sensor and the first name? as an aggregation?

Greetings and thank you.

Comment: Not sure of getting your point... About "The information returns it in the following way, everything above the id and the type this is normal?", what do you think is not normal? Could you provide more detail, pls? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

you should use an ISO8601 DateTime for your timestamps

"metadata": {
                "timestamp": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "value": "2019-12-12T12:00:00Z"
                }
            }